# Zero divisors in polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

The following is an exercise in Hungerford (Ch. III, ex. 5.6).

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. If $f=a_nx^n+\dots+a_0$ is a zero divisor
>   in $R[x]$, then there exists a nonzero $b$ in $R$ such that $ba_n=ba_{n-1}=\dots=ba_0=0$.

I can see for example that $\{g\in R[x]\mid fg=0\}$ is a nonzero ideal, so it contains a nonzero element of smallest degree.  But how to show that such an element is actually a constant?

Comment: I gave [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227694/why-is-langle-x2-xy-y3-rangle-primary-in-kx-y-z/227787#227787) a complete solution to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *McCoy's theorem*, for which you can find a nice summary and information on in [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83171/29335).